# Veryfing a proof without a truth table

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification

I have the following proof to verify without using truth tables but rather to use the laws or theorems of logical equivalence.

I am suppose to prove $(p\wedge q)\vee p\equiv p$, but I am stuck at$(p\wedge p)\vee (p\wedge q)\equiv p$ Distributive Law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've started out in a way that isn't really helpful. Instead of *distributing* the $p$, you want to instead *factor out* a $p$. (Remember this isn't quite like addition and multiplication; both of these operations distribute over each other.) So, write
\begin{align*}
(p \wedge ~q) \vee p
&= (p \wedge ~q) \vee (p \wedge 1) \\
&= p \wedge (~q \vee 1) \\
&= p \wedge 1 \\
&= p
\end{align*}
and you're done.

Comment: Yes lol redid it and started with the commutative law first , and got it. Thanks for the answer @Mike